Tokens are no longer displayed
when I looked at the wallet this morning, all tokens except SOL disappeared. Does anyone know what this could be? The tokens are still available on Solscan. I initially thought I was hacked, but the tokens are still there.

This just happened to me too. Mini heart attack but scanners say assets are in wallet so Phantom is obviously having a bug of some kind where it's not displaying accurate wallet balances.
